# famo.us - IE - translatez issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-transforms, famo.us

I'm having difficulty in getting the translate Z working as expected in IE. Try the following code in famo.us tutorial IDE to see the difference between chrome and IE browsers. Play around with z value of translate function.

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
mainContext.setPerspective(5000);

var fs = new Surface({ content: 'hello world', size: [100, 100],
properties: {backgroundColor: 'red'}});

var ss = new Surface({ content: 'second world', size: [80, 80],
properties: {backgroundColor: 'blue'}});

var mod1 = new StateModifier({
  transform: Transform.translate(0, 0, 100)
});
var mod2 = new StateModifier({
  transform: Transform.translate(0, 0, 50)
});

mainContext.add(mod1).add(fs);
mainContext.add(mod2).add(ss);
```

IE version: 11.x, windows 8.1
Please share if you have come across this situation.

Answer (score 0):

IE currently has a bug affecting the stability of 3D transforms in CSS. IE also doesn't implement `preserve-3d` which is critical to supporting Famo.us 3D transforms correctly. This is however in development for a [future release](http://status.modern.ie/csstransformspreserve3d).

Comment: Hi Kraig Walker, thanks for clarification. However, does this mean that, I should not use famo.us to develop any desktop web application? (where supporting IE is mandatory)

Comment: Not right now I'm afraid - at leas if you need anything to reliably work on the z-axis. To my understanding Famo.us are actively working with Microsoft to figure out the issue, and see it gets the attention it needs, and even see if they can polyfill a fix synthetically. But right now IE is a no-go and it's official not supported by famo.us as of yet.

Comment: Thank you Kraig Walker. Mean while, let me try figuring out a work around, as I'm a long way in my project and there is no going back.